# Visual Studio 2015. C#. How to set image from local drive to image.Source window universal app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I would like to set image object in c# with an image from my local drive without adding it to my project.

The image is stored on my local drive:

```
C:\Users\Nero\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App1\Image\Landing Image\Landing image2.png
```

And I try to load it with this code:

```
Uri imageUri = new Uri("C:/Users/Nero/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/App1/Image/Landing Image/Landing image2.png");
landingImage.Source = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
```

There is no error in debug mode but image is not shown when I run simulator.

Comment: "But image is not show when I run simulator." does the file path exist in the "simulator"?

Answer (score 1):

When you build and deploy the app the image is no longer in that location (`C:\Users\Nero\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App1\Image\Landing Image\Landing image2.png`). But it's packaged inside the appx file that is deployed to the simulator.

To reach files in your project (and hence your appx) the simplest way is to use this:

```
Uri imageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Image/Landing Image/Landing image2.png");

landingImage.Source = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

I never developed an universal app but I found the following link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Which explains file access and might help you out.

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appx:///file.txt");
```